# Use Firebase server timestamp in Firebase URL

Tags: java, swift, firebase

I would like to use the current time of the Firebase servers in a Firebase URL. Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
Firebase(url: "https://location.firebaseio.com/logs/<firebase_time_stamp>")
Firebase(url: "https://location.firebaseio.com/logs/" + Firebase.TIME_STAMP)
```

Is there anyway to do this? If so, I need it to be workable in Swift and Java. I know you can do something like this as a child but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hello! This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). It would probably save a lot of time and energy if you start with a detailed description of the problem set and any constraints/approaches you've already ruled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase server-side timestamp ([iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_timestamp), [Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#servervalue_TIMESTAMP)) can only be used in values, not in keys.

The closest approximation I can think of is to use the client-side time of the underlying platform and the offset that Firebase keeps track off. Rob gives a pretty good explanation of that [here](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/issues/1#issuecomment-22778431):

> There is no way to get the server time synchronously from Firebase, but the local time + server offset time (provided immediately whenever you write to Firebase using the ServerValue) is a good approximation.

Also see this section of the [documentation that introduces  `/.info/serverTimeOffset`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-latency).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ServerValue.timestamp()` for swift 4.0.

```
let timeStamp = ServerValue.timestamp()

let str = "https://location.firebaseio.com/logs/\(timeStamp)"
```